# How to count cells in a specific range with Pandas in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, count

For example, I want to count the filled cells in the range C5 to C25 or D8 to D17. I can't use header names.

How can I do that?

dataxls = pd.read_excel('Racklist.xlsx', header=None)

Comment: I wouldn't use pandas for this. Perhaps try openpyxl. If you have to use pandas, you could try a combination of `usecols` and `skiprows`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and their linked pages. We'd like to see code showing your attempt to solve the problem. Currently, you don't do that, so it looks like you're asking us to write code for you, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
 dataxls = pd.read_excel("YOUR_FILE_NAME.xlsx", 'Sheet1',  usecols = "C", header = 4, nrows=25)
 num_filled_cells = dataxls.shape[0] - dataxls.isnull().sum().values[0]
 print(num_filled_cells)
```